# Why does this POSIX sh function set $? = 1

Tags: sh, posix

Very simple script but no idea why it sends an exit code of 1...

```
docker run --rm -it alpine
/ # apk update && apk add curl
...
...
/ # func() { RESPCODE=$(curl -sS -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1); EXITCODE=$?; [ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ] && return 2; }
/ # func
/ # echo $?
1
```

Why does it not exit with zero code?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We assume `curl` suceeds.
- `EXITCODE=0`
- From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html: `The exit status of an AND list shall be the exit status of the last command that is executed in the list.`
- `[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ]` exits with `1` exit status
- `return 2` does not execute
- the last command in `[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ] && return 2` is `[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ]`
- `[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ]` exited with `1` exit status
- so the exit status of `[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ] && return 2` is 1
- the last command in a function exited with `1` exit status.
- the function exits with `1` exit status
- `echo $?` outputs `1`

Do not use `&&` nor `||` as a condition. Use `if`.

Comment: Re "*Do not use `&&` nor `||` as a condition. Use `if`.*", `[ $EXITCODE -eq 0 ] || return 2` would work fine here.